# Solve $a z - b \bar{z}^2 - c z^2 \bar{z} = 0$

Tags: complex-numbers

How to solve the equation 
$$ a z - b \bar{z}^2 - c  z^2 \bar{z} = 0 $$
for $z \in \mathbb{C}$ where $a, b, c \in \mathbb{C}$ are known coeffients. 
I want to solve for z. 
I started with substituting $z = r \, \mathrm{e}^{i \theta}$ to arrive at
$$ a - b \, r \, \mathrm{e}^{-i 3 \theta} - c \, r^2 = 0 $$
but I'm not sure how to continue from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: using that $\,z\bar z = |z|^2\,$ the equation can be written as:

$$
\begin{align}
a z - b \bar{z}^2 - c  z |z|^2 = 0 \\
\iff\;\; \left(a - c|z|^2\right) z = b \bar z^2 \tag{1}
\end{align}
$$

Taking conjugates on both sides:

$$
\left(\bar a - \bar c|z|^2\right) \bar z = \bar b z^2 \tag{2}
$$

Multiplying $(1) \cdot (2)\,$:

$$
\left(a - c|z|^2\right) \left(\bar a - \bar c|z|^2\right) |z|^2 = |b|^2 |z|^4 \\
\iff\;\;|z|^2 \cdot \left(|c|^2|z|^4-\left(|b|^2+a \bar c + \bar a c\right)|z|^2+|a|^2\right) = 0
$$

The latter gives the obvious root $\,z=0\,$, and the second factor is a biquadratic in $\,|z|\,$ with real coefficients. Any real positive roots can then be substituted back in $(1)$ and solved for $z$.